# Can alternate Android browsers (such as Firefox) use features not supported by an older default browser?

Tags: testing, android

I frequently use http://caniuse.com for quick web browser support reference on particular HTML/CSS element.

There is "Android Browser" column with a note that reads:

> Android browser/WebView version numbers through 4.4 refer to the
>   version of Android OS. Support listed is for the Android core; it
>   should be noted that many hardware vendors (Samsung, HTC, etc.) use
>   altered version of their default browser which may include
>   more/less/buggy support.
>
> Starting in Android 5, the web engine can be updated separately, so
>   the latest Chromium version number is used instead.

What does that mean in respect of not using the default Android browser but rather using a web browser installed as Android application (Firefox, Chrome, etc.)?

For example there are CSS filters (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters), that are supported:

- Firefox >= 44
- Chrom >= 47
- Android Browser >= 4.4

If a user has **Android 4.3**, but is using **Firefox for Android 45** will this feature work?

Comment: Firefox on Android and the desktop both use the same rendering engine so the HTML and CSS should be the same.